# We are using Epson.Xamarin.Android package and getting error after Run Exception of type 'Epson.Xamarin.Android.Epos2.Epos2Exception' was thrown

Tags: android, xamarin, printing, epos

```
var printer = new Printer(Serie.TmM30, Model.Chinese, BaseContext);
printer.Connect("192.168.2.11", 9100);                 printer.AddText("Hello, world!\n");
printer.AddText("This is a sample text.\n");
printer.AddText("Thank you for using Epson printers.\n");                 
printer.SendData(200);
printer.Disconnect();
```

Using Above code compile an run successfully but getting **Exception of type 'Epson.Xamarin.Android.Epos2.Epos2Exception' was thrown.**

Comment: Please any one having update on this it will help us lot.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't Epson have its own documentation to help you with this?